# Import blog to Jekyll - what is this load error 'require cannot load such file'?

Tags: import, rubygems, jekyll

From the related questions that popped up, it looks like I'm missing a dependencey (Ubuntu 16.04). But I have the dependencies listed in the [installation guide](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/#requirements/), and also bundler, because when I tried to set up a new project it gave an error saying that was needed. Once that was installed I ran `jekyll new my-site` and it set up all the folders and files fine. Then I exported my blog to an xml file, and typed in the command to [import it into jekyll](http://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/blogger/):

```
$ ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import";
JekyllImport::Importers::Blogger.run({
"source"        =>"/Downloads/blog-01-18-2017.xml",
})'
```

But it gave me this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot 
load such file -- jekyll-import (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

How can I figure out what dependency is missing? Is there something else I should do?

Comment: What step of the installation process fails?

Comment: @marcanuy The installation went fine, let me clarify that in the question. All the folders and files for the new project have been made, but when i try to import the xml of the blog, this is what happens. The first 4 lines of code are the import command, the last 4 are the error.

Comment: Did you install it `gem install jekyll-import`?

Comment: @marcanuy No, that wasn't the recommended method. I just followed the instructions on the page on the Jekyll site on [importing Blogger](http://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/blogger/).

Comment: @marcanuy ooh - i see somehow i skipped a page of the instructions... doing that now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before using `jekyll-import` you need to [install](http://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/) it:

```
$ gem install jekyll-import
```

> Because the importers have many of their own dependencies, they are
>   made available via a separate gem called jekyll-import. To use them,
>   all you need to do is install the gem, and they will become available
>   as part of Jekyll’s standard command line interface.

Comment: It executed now, but i don't see the output. Was i supposed to do this from within the project folder?

Comment: did it generate the posts?

Comment: No. I'm very noob here but there is nothing new in the project folder, none of the files there is that. I ran the command and it gave me a new prompt with no messages, but i don't see the output.

Comment: Yes - that was it. I had to run that from the folder. Thanks for your help.